# How do I set a resource file to non-embedded

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resources

In Visual studio 2008 is it possible to have a resource file that is included as a separate file after compilation rather than as an embedded resource.  This is to enable small changes to be rolled out more easily.

I have tried build options of Resource, None, Compile and also copy local on and off for most of these.  However when ever I try access the resource at run time I get a cannot find resource exception.

Is this actually possible or am I wasting my time?

Answer (score 1):

How are trying to access this *resource*? If you set the copy local to true you could read it as a simple file:

```
var contents = File.ReadAllBytes("somefile");
```

- Build Action: `Content`
- Copy to Output Directory: `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`

Comment: I am trying to use My.Resources.

Comment: `My.Resources` is used to read embedded resources in the assembly. It is not designed to read files on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Content** option. With this option the file is not compiled, but is included in the Content output group

Take a look on [File Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx)

Comment: I have already tried Resource, Compile, None and Embedded Resource, the latter is the only one that works.